# iOS Hide TextView and not retain height

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextview

I have some UITextviews in my controller and I check if they have content. If not, I set them hidden. The problem is that even though i hide it, it retains its height. What can I do for it?

```
if([self.history.text length]<1)
{
    [historyLabel setHidden:TRUE];
    [history setHidden:TRUE];

}
```

Comment: historyLabel.hidden=yes;

Comment: make sure you've bind your label and textview in IB.

Answer (score 0):

```
if([self.history.text length]<1)
{
    [self.history setHidden:YES];
    [historyLabel setHidden:YES];
}
```

Try this..